# Determine if user has hotfix # 981889 installed?

Tags: firewall, anti-virus, content-filter, windows

I want to know if a particular computer has MS HotFix #981889 installed. To do that I check file versions. [This page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981889) lists file versions that the hotfix deals with. **However, I cannot figure out:**

- Do the file versions correspond with the **version the hotfix installs**?
- OR do the versions listed on that page correspond to the **unpatched version** which the hotfix **replaces**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file versions listed are those included in the hotfix.  If all the files are of the version listed or above, *and* the hotfix appears as installed in Add/Remove Programs (or Programs and Features for Vista and later) then the hotfix is installed.

If the files are of the version listed or above, but the hotfix does not appear in Add/Remove Programs, then it is *probably* not needed, but I would recommend installing it anyway, because in some cases hotfixes include registry changes as well as file updates.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that if you need to do this in software, you can look in SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall to see whether the hotfix is in Add/Remove Programs or not.

Comment: Yes, if the fix is included in a service pack, and you can confirm that the service pack is installed, then just look at the file versions.  (Even that is only necessary if you're feeling paranoid!)

Answer (score 6):

open open powershell then do

get-hotfix | findstr  "981889"

for remote

get-hotfix -computername svrname | findstr  "981889"

Comment: Can I do this in C?

Comment: yes but why? that would be more work then required and more likely to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The file versions correspond to the files the hotfix installs.